# PPTP VPN not working on Yosemite 10.10.3 with OS X Server 4.1

Tags: macos, osx-server, vpn

I've set up a VPN on my Mac mini using Server 4.1 with the "L2TP and PPTP" option set.  I can connect to the VPN from my iPhone over my local network (Time Capsule) using L2TP but not PPTP.  With the latter the VPN service log shows the error

```
DSAuth plugin: MPPE key required, but its retrieval failed.
```

I've Googled around the subject and found various answers saying my "VPN MPPE Key Access User" dismissing/corrupt and I need to recreate it using `sudo vpnaddkeyagentuser /LDAPv3/127.0.0.1`.  These posts tend to point back to this article - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201828.

I've tried this, but I don't see the user being added to the list in Server (yes, I clicked on View > Show System Accounts).

Comment: I thought I had it!  I'm not running Open Directory so there isn't an LDAP server on my network.  I therefore need to run `sudo vpnaddkeyagentuser` without further arguments to add the missing account.  And that does work - I can see it in the Server.app user list.  However, I still get the MPPE key retrieval error.  Grrrr!

Comment: The log also contains this - `DSAuth plugin: unsupported authen authority: recved ShadowHash;HASHLIST:<SMB-NT,CRAM-MD5,RECOVERABLE,SALTED-SHA512-PBKDF2>, want ApplePasswordServer` - relevant?

Comment: Open Directory log contains this - `Client: vpnaddkeyagentu, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0` `Node: /Local/Default, Module: PlistFile - unable to update FDE password - missing critical information`

Comment: Hmmm... serious lack of comment on this one!  I did some more digging and found https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT4748 which says "PPTP can only be used if you are managing network users or users connected to a directory server. Local user accounts can only be used with LT2P." so perhaps I'm flogging a dead horse.  I know I used to be able to use PPTP with iVPN so perhaps I'll go back to that, or just stick with L2TP since it's working fine for me.

Comment: I have a similar problem in the revers though. PPTP is working fine but L2TP is not.. i am also running open directory on my Yosemite server.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for being untechnical, but I solved a VPN/Yosemite issue: After a smaller Upgrade my VPN still connected, but didn’t let anything thru. The Update somehow „unchecked“ System Preferences > Network > VPN(PPTP) > More…/Options > Connecting Option > Send all traffic through VPN Connection (third option in the first list in this dialog; I'm translating/guessing from the german version). Setting it back to let everything go through resolved all issues; Mail, afp, ftp, vnc came back just like that.